# Complex Integration by Parts help

Tags: integration, complex-integration

Solve $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\sigma^2/(4t)}(\sigma^2 +2\sigma x+x^2-1)d\sigma$

I am told the integral of the heat kernel is 1

Answer (score 1):

This one is veeery similar to the one you just asked about :)

First write $\sigma^2 + 2\sigma  x + x^2 = (\sigma + x)^2$ then

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} (\sigma + x)^2 e^{-\sigma^2 /(4t)}d\sigma - \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\sigma^2 /(4t)}d\sigma$$

Use the variable change $y=\sigma + x$ for the first integral and multiply and divide by $\sqrt{4\pi t}$ to make the integrand be a density kernel:

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} (\sigma + x)^2 e^{-\sigma^2 /(4t)}d\sigma  = \sqrt{4\pi t}  \int_{\mathbb{R}} y^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} e^{-(y-x)^2 /(4t)}dy = \sqrt{4\pi t}  (2t + x^2)$$
since it is the second order moment of a NON-centered Gaussian random variable (or heat kernel) with mean $x$ and variance $2t$, (i.e. if $X\sim N(x,2t)$ then $E(X^2) = Var(X) + E(X)^2 = 2t+x^2$.

Finally
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\sigma^2 /(4t)}d\sigma = \sqrt{4\pi t} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} e^{-\sigma^2 /(4t)}d\sigma = \sqrt{4\pi t}$$
since the integral is 1.

Altogether, as before,
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} (\sigma^2 + 2\sigma  x + x^2-1) e^{-\sigma^2 /(4t)}d\sigma = 2t + x^2 - 1.$$

Comment: You're the man! Not really got the hang of Guassian integrals yet! :)

Comment: A Gaussian density with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ is defined as: $f(x;\mu,\sigma^2) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{- \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ and as you know it satisfies $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x;\mu,\sigma^2) dx = 1$, and has mean $\int_{\mathbb{R}} x f(x;\mu,\sigma^2) dx = \mu$ and second order moment $\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2 f(x;\mu,\sigma^2) dx = \sigma^2 + \mu^2$. Using these three properties you can compute your integrals above as I showed you. It is also called heat kernel btw.